# Is It possible to email interactive charts using Plotly, Dash, or Streamlit?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, streamlit, plotly.js

I wanted to write code to load in some data, graph it with Plotly, organize it in either a streamlit or dash dashboard, and email these insights to colleagues on Microsoft Outlook that they can interact with (e.g., zooming in and hovering over data points). However, after doing some initial research I havent really found anything besides this: https://plotly.com/python/v3/email-reports/ and I am unsure if this is even possible. Does anyone have any ideas or experiences with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Any Plotly chart can be statically exported either PNG or SVG - you can attach these to email
- If you create your dashboard as Jupyter Notebook, you can use `nbconvert` to turn your notebook to static PDF file and attach this file to an email

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think my question wasn't worded properly. I know how to code streamlit and plotly, and include screenshots or png's in an email, but I was wondering if there was a way to maintain the interactive piece of the plotly charts on the recipient's email, so when they open the email, the charts are dynamic.

Comment: That's not how email works. Please include a link to a interactive website in the email.